# Using class tree to delete specific HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html

How can I use vanilla JS to find and delete elements with a specific class X where the parent has class Y?

Example. Given

```
<div class="likes noise1">
   <div class="count noise2">
       42
   </div>
</div>
<div class="retweets noise3">
   <div class="count noise4">
       7
   </div>
</div>
<div class="messages noise5">
   <div class="count noise6">
       2
   </div>
</div>
```

I would like to delete the first two ".count" elements (the childs of ".likes" and ".retweets"). The messages div however should be left untouched.

I have tried using querySelectorAll which return a frozen NodeList and iterating it, without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through all the elements to check the [`Element.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) property of the [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) to remove the element like the following way:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.count').forEach(function(el){
  var classN = el.parentNode.className
  if(classN.includes('likes') || classN.includes('retweets'))
    el.remove();
});
```

```html
<div class="likes">
   <div class="count">
       42
   </div>
</div>
<div class="retweets">
   <div class="count">
       7
   </div>
</div>
<div class="messages">
   <div class="count">
       2
   </div>
</div>
```

**OR:** You can simply simply specify both the classes as part of the selector, in which case you do not need to check the *parentNode* as the selector will give you only the elements inside the parents:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.likes > .count, .retweets > .count').forEach(function(el){
  el.parentNode.remove();    
});
```

```html
<div class="likes">
   <div class="count">
       42
   </div>
</div>
<div class="retweets">
   <div class="count">
       7
   </div>
</div>
<div class="messages">
   <div class="count">
       2
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `let found = document.querySelectorAll('.likes .count, .retweets .count')` will get _just_ the `.count` nodes for likes and retweets — no need to check the parent node class in the javascript.

Comment: Thanks, this is great! I had an issue in my application there are lots of other classes which breaks the solution. I edited the if clause to something like classN.includes('retweets') to solve that

Comment: @StephenP, I have updated answer including the solution, thanks:)

Comment: @Anders, you are most welcome....please notice the second answer as Stephen suggested in the comment:)

Comment: @StephenP and Mamun you made my day. Thanks! Mamun, Im sending a edit suggestion (I dont want to delete parent only inner element)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, further to those already given is to keep an array of the css selector you'll need to find your targets. From there, it's just a simple matter of using `querySelector` so that the result is still live, albeit in a loop.

```js
 "use strict";
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
window.addEventListener('load', onWindowLoaded, false);

function onWindowLoaded(evt)
{
 var tgtSelectors = [ '.likes > .count', '.retweets > .count' ];
 tgtSelectors.forEach(removeBySelector);
}

function removeBySelector(curSelector)
{
 var tgt = document.querySelector(curSelector);
 while (tgt != undefined)
 {
  tgt.remove();
  tgt = document.querySelector(curSelector);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="likes">
 <div class="count">42</div>
</div>

<div class="retweets">
 <div class="count">7</div>
</div>

<div class="messages">
 <div class="count">2</div>
</div>
```